# not able to generate a signed apk with same SHA-1,

Tags: android

I am creating an in-app purchase app. I have uploaded apk file once while creating the application in Google Play developer console. But now when I am trying to upload another version of apk file it is showing error of different SHA-1 keys. I have changed the version code and package name is also same. I referred questions here and I got to know that apk should be signed with same certificate.

But my problem is when I export the project from Eclipse to generate signed apk it is not allowing to use existing keystore; moreover when I select existing keystore the dropdown list of alias are empty. So each time I have to create new keystore. Also it is showing "Invalid keystore format" on selecting exiting keystore. Please provide me with some solution to how can I generate an APK with same SHA-1 key.

Comment: You have to use the same keystore for all versions of your app. If the alias field is empty it means that you entered a wrong keystore password.

Comment: i am sure about this that i am entring the same password. i have tried many times.

Answer (score 0):

Is this apk file generated from another computer than the first? 
Make sure to have the same .keyStore file on your different PC.

Comment: no i am generating it from the same computer. my problem is eclipse is not allowing me to use the existing keystore as alias name dropdown is empty.